# Number of copies of irreducible representation in another representation

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Let $V,W$ be complex finite dimensional representation spaces of a finite group $G$ with representations $\rho$ and $\sigma$ respectively. I read that if $V$ is irreducible, then the dimension of the space of $G$-module homomorphism from $V$ to $W$ is the number of copies of  $V$ in $W$. I think I understand the idea, but I want to make a solid argument.

First, the space $Z=$Hom$(V,W)$ can be identified with $V^*\otimes W$, so that the action of $G$ in $Z$ is given by $$\phi\mapsto g\phi=\sigma(g)\circ \phi\circ \rho(g^{-1}).$$ So that an element $\phi$ of $Z$ is a $G$-module homomorphism if and only if $\phi\in Z^G$. It follows that dim$Z^G$ is the number of copies of the trivial representation in $Z$. I think this is basically it, but I cannot make formal the idea that $\mathbb C^*$ being a subrepresentation of $V^*\otimes W$ implies that $V$ is a subrepresentation of $W$.

Comment: This construction is used to prove the orthogonality relations, but to prove the result you want you only need to repeatedly apply Schur's lemma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can decompose $W$ into irreducibles, $W = \oplus_{i = 1}^n V_i$, and use $Hom_G(V, \oplus V_i) = \oplus Hom_G(V,V_i)$ - a function into a product is determined by its coordinate projections.

At this point the desired result follows from Schur's lemma, as Qiaochu says in the comments.

A pedantic linguistic quibble -- does it make sense to say 'the number of copies of V in W'? If $W = V \oplus V$, there are infinitely many copies of $V$ inside of $W$ (can you describe all of them?). The concept you want instead is 'the dimension of the V-isotypic subspace.' Alternatively, it would be accurate to say  "the number of copies of V in a decomposition of W into irreducibles" or "the multiplicity of $V$ in $W$."